# Returnurl not working with internal SSO - php?

Tags: php, iis, redirect, authentication, windows-server-2008

I have a login system that I would like to introduce to my subsites on my web server but users are not getting redirected back to their correct place after login.

Right now the SSO sends the user to -

```
https://site.com/home/index.php?email=first.last@thomsonreuters.com&firstname=First&lastname=Last&marketgroup=43003&uid=4334525&time=2014:07:24:19:14:57&digest=1758b84916f36245cad17fd325f8d3&returnurl=https://site.com/sandbox/subsite
```

So the user keeps getting redirected back to site.com even though the returnurl is set for a subdirectory.  Not sure what the next step is here.

Code snippet below.  Please tell me if you need more.

```
define('SSO_REDIRECT', 'https://sso.com/login/sso/SSOService?app=' . SSO_APP_ID . '&returnurl=' . urlencode('https://site.com/sandbox/subsite'));

// Start authentication and authorization
if (!isset($_SESSION['USER_ID']) && !isset($_POST['digest'])) {
    // We've got no session and we've not returned from SSO, so let's redirect to SSO
    header('Location: ' . SSO_REDIRECT);
    die();
}
```

Comment: What are you using to do the redirecting? ` header("Location: "...` or something else. Please post more of your code.

Comment: @Athafoud - added some of the source.

Comment: So you are redirecting to the SSO and the SSO re-redirects to the `returnurl` if I understand. So I think the problem is under the code running at sso.com/login.....

Comment: @Athafoud - yes.  The SSO tells me to use the returnurl variable.  It is going to web root I am sure because that is the url i gave them to set up the application.